# Pass in an iterator that iterates only elements satisfying certain conditions

Tags: c++

In C++, is it possible to pass in an iterator that iterates only elements satisfying certain conditions? While it is certainly possible to write my own iterator class, I'm wondering there exists a standard library solution. For example, the constructor of `std::discrete_distribution` takes an input of two iterators (begin and end). Now I would need to do the following:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> y;
std::copy_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::back_inserter(y), my_condition);
std::discrete_distribution dd(y.begin(), y.end());
```

But this would require to copy the elemnts of `y` twice. I would prefer something like following:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::discrete_distribution dd(std::condition_iter(x.begin(), my_condition), x.end());
```

Comment: You could derive your own iterator class from `std::vector::iterator` and override the `operator++` to use your condition. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772860/c-iterator-over-certain-elements-in-vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is neither special syntax nor standard library feature in C++ which could solve your problem. However, there is a library called "range-v3" that might help. Here are a couple of links:
https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3
https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/
Look for `view::remove_if` - I think this is what you need. This will filter the container on the fly without actually modifying anything.